# join two queries together as one - django

Tags: django

I am working on a django project and I want to basically create one query out of two queries that I was creating.

I have a friends table that has the following columns

```
user - friend - status - create
-------------------------------
josh - omar - 1 - 1
steve - omar - 1 - 1
omar - tava - 1 - 1
```

I would create one query to grab records where the user is omar and another one to grab records where the friend is omar.

is there a way to create a query that would combine the two queries like

Grab all the records where omar is a friend or user and set them as one queryset object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Q
Friend.object.filter(Q(user=omar)|Q(friend=omar))
```

or

```
queryset = queryset1 | queryset2
```

Comment: The 1st approach is faster because it only makes 1 Query to the database. The 2nd one does 2 queries and then uses python to combine the two querysets.

Comment: @ShikharChauhan plain wrong - the second solution is strictly equivalent to the first, and issues one single query with a OR in the where clause. You could have found this out by yourself just trying it out in a shell and inspecting `django.db.connection.queries`.

Comment: @Ykh the `.all()` is redundant - `.filter()` already returns a `Queryset`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thank you for pointing out. I'll look into this :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want to take a look at Q objects. These allow you to just what you describe ... conduct two separate queries, and add the results together. 
[complex-lookups-with-q-objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

The documentation has an example that shows you can do an 'or' lookup as follows:

`Q(question__startswith='Who') | Q(question__startswith='What')`